# Setting UITextView Cursor Position

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have multiple `uitextviews` with their respective light gray placeholder text onLoad. Delegates are properly set.

My goal is, on any `uitextview` tap, to have the cursor selected to the start of the `uitextview` if the placeholder is present.

My problem is when I initially tap outside the placeholder text range (the blank space without text), the `textviewdidchangeselection` delegate doesn't even fire and the cursor begins at the end of the placeholder text. When I initially tap the placeholder text things work properly. When I initially tap the placeholder text and then try to tap outside the placeholder text range, things also work properly.

Any thoughts on why it is behaving the way it is? I tried both `.selectedRange` and `.selectedTextRange` to no avail.

```
func onLoad() {
    textView1.text = placeHolderText1
    textView1.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    
    textView2.text = placeHolderText2
    textView2.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    
    textView1.textContainerInset.left = 4
    textView1.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    textView1.layer.masksToBounds = true
    textView1.delegate = self
    
    textView2.textContainerInset.left = 4
    textView2.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    textView2.layer.masksToBounds = true
    textView2.delegate = self
}

func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if self.view.window != nil {
        if textView == textView1 {
            if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray && textView.text == placeHolderText1 {
                textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: textView.beginningOfDocument)
            }
        } else if textView == textView2 {
            if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray && textView.text == placeHolderText2 {
                textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus I had actually tried updating from the main thread, but it did not solve the behavior i'm encountering...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, your final goal is to have a working placeholder?
If yes, you can try this code:

```
//TextView place holder
extension UITextView{
    func setPlaceholder() {
        let placeholderLabel = UILabel()
        placeholderLabel.text = "Enter your hashtags ..."
        placeholderLabel.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: (self.font?.pointSize)!)
        placeholderLabel.sizeToFit()
        placeholderLabel.tag = 222
        placeholderLabel.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 5, y: (self.font?.pointSize)! / 2)
        placeholderLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        placeholderLabel.isHidden = !self.text.isEmpty
        self.addSubview(placeholderLabel)
    }

    func checkPlaceholder() {
        let placeholderLabel = self.viewWithTag(222) as! UILabel
        placeholderLabel.isHidden = !self.text.isEmpty
    }
}
```

with this code in your viewController class that has the UItextViewDelegate:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView1.checkPlaceholder()
    textView2.checkPlaceholder()
}
```

and this code in your viewController class viewDidload:

```
   textView1.setPlaceholder()
   textView2.setPlaceholder()
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, and ultimately yes, that is the final goal. Just wondering if there's a solution based on my current setup though.

Comment: You can keep the setup and layouts that you have defined in func onLoad. As this is a textView extension, where ever you need a placeholder for a textview just do: yourtextView.setPlaceholer